# compile shell script so can use suid

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, compilation, suid

I need to suid a script so that it can be executed by users with less permissions.  Since you can't suid a script and can only suid an executable I wanted to use the generic script compiler "shc" to create an executable and then set that executable's suid bit.  Only problem is that on ubuntu jaunty I can't find shc or when I do apt-get install shc, it's comes back as not found.  Is there an alternative to using shc (except writing my own C program) or is it included into a repo that I could add, so that apt-get would find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had [this same question over on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8449/cannot-set-uid-on-shell-scripts) - you can edit the sudoers file to grant permission to run a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the script use `sudo` to execute any administrative commands.

If you need sudo to work without requiring a password look at editing the sudoers file to specify the script and give the NOPASSWD option something like this.

USERNAME ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/SCRIPT_NAME ""

Comment: will that not prompt the user for a password, I just want them to be able to execute ./somescript and be done with it, I don't want them to have to know the password of the user account that the script runs as.